# How does simply piping to the response object render data to the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filestream

In the example code in [this article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/11/better-than-gzip-compression-with-brotli/), how is the last segment of the stream working on the line:

```
fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(brotli()).pipe(res)
```

I understand that the first part reading the file, the second is compressing it, but what is `.pipe(res)`? which seems to do the job I'd usually do with `res.send` or `res.sendFile`.

Full code<sup>†</sup>:

```
const accepts = require('accepts')
const brotli = require('iltorb').compressStream
function onRequest (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
  const fileName = req.params.fileName
  const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'files', fileName)
  const encodings = new Set(accepts(req).encodings())
  if (encodings.has('br')) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'br')
    fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(brotli()).pipe(res)
  }
}
const app = express()
app.use('/files/:fileName', onRequest)
```

> `localhost:5000/files/test.txt => Browser displays text contents of that file`

#### How does simply piping the data to the response object render the  data back to the client?

<sup>† which I changed slightly to use express, and a few other minor stuff.</sup>

Comment: `res` is also stream. So you can pipe to it. Don't forget call `res.destroy()` on read error.

Comment: @AikonMogwai Okay, I see that now. But how exactly does it work that you can just "pipe to it". That's what I'm not following...

Answer (score 19):

> "How does simply piping the data to the response object render the data back to the client?"

The wording of *"the response object"* in the question could mean the asker is trying to understand **why piping data from a stream to `res` does anything**. The misconception is that `res` is just some object.

This is because all [express Responses](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res) (`res`) inherit from [`http.ServerResponse`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) ([on this line](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/4.16.2/lib/response.js#L42)), **which is a writable `Stream`**. Thus, whenever data is written to `res`, the written data is handled by `http.ServerResponse` which internally sends the written data back to the client.

Internally, `res.send` actually just writes to the underlying stream it represents (itself). [`res.sendFile` actually *pipes* the data](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/4.16.2/lib/response.js#L1099) read from the file to itself.

In case the act of "piping" data from one stream to another is unclear, see the section at the bottom.

---

If, instead, the **flow of data from file to client** isn't clear to the asker, then here's a separate explanation.

I'd say the first step to understanding this line is to break it up into smaller, more understandable fragments:

First, `fs.createReadStream` is used to get a [*readable* stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams) of a file's contents.

```
const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
```

Next, a [*transform* stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_duplex_and_transform_streams) that transforms data into a compressed format is created and the data in the `fileStream` is ["piped"](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) (passed) into it.

```
const compressionStream = brotli();
fileStream.pipe(compressionStream);
```

Finally, the data that passes through the `compressionStream` (the transform stream) is piped into the response, which is also a [*writable* stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_streams).

```
compressionStream.pipe(res);
```

The process is quite simple when laid out visually:

[image: stream flowchart]

Following the flow of data is now quite simple: the data first comes from a file, through a compressor, and finally to the response, which internally sends the data back to the client.

> Wait, but how does the compression stream pipe into the response stream?

The answer is that [`pipe`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) returns the *destination* stream. That means when you do `a.pipe(b)`, you'll get `b` back from the method call.

Take the line `a.pipe(b).pipe(c)` for example. First, `a.pipe(b)` is evaluated, returning `b`. Then, `.pipe(c)` is called on the result of `a.pipe(b)`, which is `b`, thus being equivalent to `b.pipe(c)`.

[image: <code>pipe</code> flowchart]

```
a.pipe(b).pipe(c);

// is the same as

a.pipe(b); // returns `b`
b.pipe(c);

// is the same as

(a.pipe(b)).pipe(c);
```

The wording "imply piping the data to the response object" in the question could also entail the asker doesn't understand the flow of the data, thinking that the data goes directly from `a` to `c`. Instead, the above should clarify that the data goes from `a` to `b`, then `b` to `c`; `fileStream` to `compressionStream`, then `compressionStream` to `res`.

---

#### A Code Analogy

If the whole process still makes no sense, it might be beneficial to rewrite the process without the concept of streams:

First, the data is read from the file.

```
const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
```

The `fileContents` are then compressed. This is done using some `compress` function.

```
function compress(data) {
    // ...
}

const compressedData = compress(fileContents);
```

Finally, the data is sent back to the client through the response `res`.

```
res.send(compressedData);
```

The original line of code in the question and the above process are more or less the same, barring the inclusion of streams in the original.

The act of taking some data in from an outside source (`fs.readFileSync`) is like a readable `Stream`. The act of transforming the data (`compress`) via a function is like a transform `Stream`. The act of sending the data to an outside source (`res.send`) is like a writable `Stream`.

---

#### "Streams are Confusing"

If you're confused about how streams work, here's a simple analogy: each type of stream can be thought of in the context of water (data) flowing down the side of a mountain from a lake on the top.

- **Readable** streams are like the lake on the top, the source of the water (data).
- **Writable** streams are like people or plants at the bottom of the mountain, consuming the water (data).
- **Duplex** streams are just streams that are both Readable and Writable. They're be akin to a facility at the bottom that takes in water and puts out some type of product (i.e. purified water, carbonated water, etc.).
- **Transform** streams are also Duplex streams. They're like rocks or trees on the side of the mountain, forcing the water (data) to take a different path to get to the bottom.

A convenient way of writing all data read from a readable stream directly to a writable stream is to **just `pipe` it**, which is just directly connecting the lake to the people.

```
readable.pipe(writable); // easy & simple
```

This is in contrast to reading data from the readable stream, then manually writing it to the writable stream:

```
// "pipe" data from a `readable` stream to a `writable` one.
readable.on('data', (chunk) => {
    writable.write(chunk);
});
readable.on('end', () => writable.end());
```

You might immediately question why Transform streams are the same as Duplex streams. The only difference between the two is how they're implemented.

Transform streams implement a `_transform` function that's supposed to take in written data and return readable data, whereas a Duplex stream is simply both a Readable and Writable stream, thus having to implement `_read` and `_write`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. But I'll attempt to explain the code `fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(brotli()).pipe(res)` which might clarify your doubt, hopefully.

If you check the source code of [`iltorb`](https://github.com/MayhemYDG/iltorb/blob/master/index.js), `compressStream` returns an object of `TransformStreamEncode` which extends [`Transform`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform). As you can see Transform streams implement both the Readable and Writable interfaces. So when `fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(brotli())` is getting executed, `TransformStreamEncode`'s writable interface is used to write the data read from `filePath`. Now when the next call to `.pipe(res)` is getting executed, readable interface of `TransformStreamEncode` is used to read the compressed data and it is passed to `res`. If you check the documentation of [HTTP Response](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) object it implements the Writable interface. So it internally handles the `pipe` event to read the compressed data from Readable `TransformStreamEncode` and then sends it to client.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You ask:

> How does simply piping the data to the response object render the data back to the client?

Most people understand "render X" as "produce some visual representation of X". Sending the data to the browser (here, through piping) is a necessary step prior to rendering on the browser the file that is read from the file system, but piping is not what does the rendering. What happens is that the Express app takes the content of the file, compresses it and sends the compressed stream as-is to the browser. This is a necessary step because the browser cannot render anything if it does not have the data. So `.pipe` is only used to pass the data to the response sent to the browser.

By itself, this does not "render", nor tell the browser what to do with the data. Before the piping, this happens: `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')`. So the browser will see a header telling it that the content is HTML. Browsers know what to do with HTML: display it. So it will take the data it gets, decompress it (because the `Content-Encoding` header tells it it is compressed), interpret it as HTML, and show it to the user, that is, render it.

> what is `.pipe(res)`? which seems to do the job I'd usually do with `res.send` or `res.sendFile`.

`.pipe` is used to pass the entire content of a readable stream to a writable stream. It is a convenience method when handling streams. Using `.pipe` to send a response makes sense when you *must* read from a stream to get the data you want to include in the response. If you do not have to read from a stream, you should use `.send` or `.sendFile`. They perform nice bookkeeping tasks like setting the `Content-Length` header, that otherwise you'd have to do yourself.

In fact, the example you show is doing a poor attempt at performing content negotiation. That code should be rewritten to use `res.sendFile` to send the file to the browser, and the handling of compression should be done by a middleware designed for content negotiation, because there's much more to it than only supporting the `br` scheme.

Comment: So `.pipe(res.send)` is preferred?

Comment: Can you give an example of the middleware you reference in your last sentence? Also, `a lot more to it`: what do you mean here? Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Preferred over what? Using `.pipe` to pass the data from a readable stream to a writable stream is certainly *preferred* over listening to `data` and `end` events and manually calling `.write` and `.end` on the writable pipe. With `.pipe`, you reduce a dozen statements or more to a single line and you avoid having to deal with edge cases (`.pipe` does it for you). However, if you can just use `.sendFile`, use *that* over calling `.pipe`. As I said in my answer `.sendFile` does bookkeeping for you that you'd have to manually handle yourself if you use `.pipe` (`Content-Length` was one example).

Comment: I mean `.pipe(res.sendFile)` is preferred over `.pipe(res)`.

Comment: `.pipe(res.sendFile)` won't work. It is `res.sendFile(filePath)` instead of `fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res)`. The compression would be provided by middleware. I said there's "a lot more to it" because there are other compression schemes that are supported more broadly than `br`. The example code in your question just conks out if `br` is not supported by the browser. And this is just one aspect of content negotiation: browsers are free to list preferred content types ("I'd prefer XML but I'll take HTML.") and languages ("I prefer Chinese but I'll take English."), etc.

Comment: The general lines of content negotiation are not project-specific so by relying on a middleware you get automatic handling of 99.99% of cases, for your whole site. I know content negotiation middlewares exist for Express, but I don't have one I can specifically recommend. For Django I've relied on the content negotiation provided by django-rest-framework, but unfortunately you cannot just plop this in Express. If the only thing needed is compression there's the `compression` package but it does [not yet support brotli](https://github.com/expressjs/compression/issues/71).

Answer (score 0):

read this to obtain answer : [Node.js Streams: Everything you need to know](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93)

I'll quote interressant part :

```
a.pipe(b).pipe(c).pipe(d)
# Which is equivalent to:
a.pipe(b)
b.pipe(c)
c.pipe(d)
# Which, in Linux, is equivalent to:
$ a | b | c | d
```

so `fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(brotli()).pipe(res)` is equivalent to `var readableStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(brotli());readableStream .pipe(res)`
and

```
# readable.pipe(writable)
readable.on('data', (chunk) => {
  writable.write(chunk);
});
readable.on('end', () => {
  writable.end();
});
```

so Node.js read the file and convert it to readble stream object `fs.createReadStream(filePath)`.
Then it give to iltorb library that create another readble stream `.pipe(brotli())` (containing the compressed content) and finally pass the content to `res` which is writable stream. So nodejs call internally `res.write()` that write back to the browser.